# Line continuation in Android strings

Tags: android, python, matlab, text, textview

A textview will hold a paragraph of text just fine. The problem is specifying the text if it is long. Either hard-coded or in the strings.xml, the text needs to be one long continuous line. A line break is an actual line break. It's not like html or latex that wait for an intentional line break.  Is there a line continuation character or something like in Python or Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried this and I'm not finding an issue with long strings.

```
<string name="test">
    test test test test
    test test test test
    test test test test
    test test test test
    \n\n
    test test test test
    test test test test
    test test test test
    test test test test

    test test test test
    test test test test
    test test test test
    test test test test
</string>
```

In this example, the first break, `\n\n`, starts a new paragraph but of the all the other breaks continue in the same paragraph.

Comment: OMG!  I swear I was just getting line breaks wherever I had them in the xml, but seems just fine now. Sorry.